# socket.io emit not working properly inside express route

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I use soket.io in Node.js it's working fine, but there is an issue in the routes files.

Below is my code and flow.
I have `server.js` file where I define `io`.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);


//io from server.js
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.emit('getDevicePostData', { message : 'Hi from server!!' });
  socket.on('sendDevicePostData', function("Hi from server") {});
});


// pass io to routes file
var smart_control = require('./smart_control.js')(io);
app.use('/', smart_control);
```

And `smart_control.js` file code is below

```
module.exports = function(io) {

    router.post('/emitdata', function(req, res, next) {
        io.sockets.emit('getDevicePostData', { message : 'Hi from route!!' });
    });
return router;
}
```

Above route's emit sometimes work and sometimes does not work.

And this emit is called from angular js. I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-socket-io package in angular
Below code in angular controller:

```
mySocket.on('getDevicePostData', function(data) {

                    console.log(data);
                 });
```

Here mySocket is factory.

What is wrong in my code. Mainly problem from routes file only.

Comment: What happen when it does not work? does server shows anything related to POST? like: POST /emitdata [response code]

Comment: When i call route i did not get any response in angular  side  in this mySocket.on('getDevicePostData', function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
 });

Comment: does your router being called?

Comment: I have implemented your code in my demo and i found that post request is not being completed. so you need to manually  **end** request by using this: `res.end();`. Add this in router.post request at last.

Comment: I use res.json({data:"success"}); At the end of router post

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace `io.sockets.emit` with `io.emit`.

Here `io.sockets.emit` will emit to only connected clients and your socket factory might not be up by the time you hit the API.

Comment: I try io.emit but same issue. Some times emit properly and some time no emit